# MySql Query optimization : Order by online member

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query, which works fine:

```
SELECT
    a.i_am,a.seeking_a,
    a.zodiac,
    a.my_marital_status,
    a.city,a.country,
    a.my_age,
    a.intrested_in1,
    a.intrested_in2,
    a.intrested_in3,
    a.intrested_in4,
    a.intrested_in5,
    a.intrested_in6,
    a.user_id,
    a.picture_type,
    a.photo,
    a.block_photo,
    r.username,
    u.title,
    u.about_myself
FROM ".TBL_ABOUT_MYSELF." a 
INNER JOIN ".TBLREGISTRATION."  r ON a.user_id=r.ID 
INNER JOIN ".TBLUSERDETAILS." u ON a.user_id=u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN ".TBLSTEPS." s ON a.user_id=s.user_id 
WHERE 1 $condition $gender_condition 
ORDER BY a.user_id 
DESC LIMIT $from,10
```

it takes around **0.5 seconds** to fetch results. **There are 1,000,000 results in total.**

Now if I put join one more table (for user online status:

```
SELECT
    a.i_am,a.seeking_a,
    a.zodiac,
    a.my_marital_status,
    a.city,a.country,
    a.my_age,
    a.intrested_in1,
    a.intrested_in2,
    a.intrested_in3,
    a.intrested_in4,
    a.intrested_in5,
    a.intrested_in6,
    a.user_id,
    a.picture_type,
    a.photo,
    a.block_photo,
    r.username,
    u.title,
    u.about_myself
FROM ".TBL_ABOUT_MYSELF." a
INNER JOIN ".TBLREGISTRATION."  r ON a.user_id=r.ID 
INNER JOIN ".TBLUSERDETAILS." u ON a.user_id=u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN ".TBLSTEPS." s ON a.user_id=s.user_id
LEFT JOIN ".TBL_USER_ONLINE." ON a.user_id=o.user_id  <-- New Line
WHERE 1 $condition $gender_condition
ORDER BY o.user_id DESC, a.user_id DESC LIMIT $from,10  <-- One more order by
```

and now it takes **12 seconds** to fetch results.

How can I optimize this?

mysql Query Explained:

```
SQL result

Host: localhost
Database: mysite_new
Generation Time: Dec 06, 2012 at 09:09 AM
Generated by: phpMyAdmin 3.2.0.1 / MySQL 5.1.36-community-log
SQL query: EXPLAIN SELECT a.i_am,a.seeking_a,a.zodiac,a.my_marital_status,a.city,a.country,a.my_age,a.intrested_in1,a.intrested_in2,a.intrested_in3,a.intrested_in4,a.intrested_in5,a.intrested_in6,a.user_id,a.picture_type,a.photo,a.block_photo,r.username,u.title, u.about_myself ,o.user_id as online_user_id FROM mysite_about_myself_new a INNER JOIN mysite_user_registration_new r ON a.user_id=r.ID INNER JOIN mysite_user_details_new u ON a.user_id=u.user_id LEFT JOIN mysite_steps_new s ON a.user_id=s.user_id LEFT JOIN mysite_usersonline_new o ON a.user_id=o.user_id WHERE 1 and r.block_by_webmaster='0' and a.approved='1' and s.step1='1' AND a.i_am ='2' AND a.seeking_a = '1' ORDER BY o.user_id DESC LIMIT 0,10; 
Rows: 5

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  a   ref user_id,i_am    i_am    2   const   30011   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  o   ref user_id user_id 4   mysite_new.a.user_id    2   Using index
1   SIMPLE  s   eq_ref  user_id user_id 4   mysite_new.a.user_id    1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  u   eq_ref  user_id user_id 4   mysite_new.s.user_id    1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  r   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   mysite_new.u.user_id    1   Using where
```

**Second Explain as Asked:**

```
SQL result

Host: localhost
Database: mysite_new
Generation Time: Dec 06, 2012 at 10:02 AM
Generated by: phpMyAdmin 3.2.0.1 / MySQL 5.1.36-community-log
SQL query: EXPLAIN SELECT a.i_am,a.seeking_a,a.zodiac,a.my_marital_status,a.city,a.country,a.my_age,a.intrested_in1,a.intrested_in2,a.intrested_in3,a.intrested_in4,a.intrested_in5,a.intrested_in6,a.user_id,a.picture_type,a.photo,a.block_photo,r.username,u.title, u.about_myself ,o.user_id as online_user_id FROM mysite_about_myself_new a INNER JOIN mysite_user_registration_new r ON a.user_id=r.ID INNER JOIN mysite_user_details_new u ON a.user_id=u.user_id LEFT JOIN mysite_steps_new s ON a.user_id=s.user_id LEFT JOIN mysite_usersonline_new o ON a.user_id=o.user_id WHERE 1 and r.block_by_webmaster='0' and a.approved='1' and s.step1='1' AND a.i_am ='2' AND a.seeking_a = '1' ORDER BY a.user_id DESC LIMIT 0,10; 
Rows: 5

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  a   index   user_id,i_am    user_id 4   NULL    38  Using where
1   SIMPLE  o   ref user_id user_id 4   mysite_new.a.user_id    2   Using index
1   SIMPLE  s   eq_ref  user_id user_id 4   mysite_new.a.user_id    1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  u   eq_ref  user_id user_id 4   mysite_new.s.user_id    1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  r   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   mysite_new.u.user_id    1   Using where
```

Comment: Should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: is *a.user_id* and *o.user_id* indexed?

Comment: Also show us your indexes/schema, and show us an `EXPLAIN` of the query.

Comment: yes.. a.user_id and o.user_id are indexed ..

Comment: Put the `EXPLAIN` command in front of your query that takes long and show the results. Even the 0.5 seconds from the first query would be too long for me.

Comment: Why are you having columns like `interested_in1` to `interested_in6`. Thre should ring a bell when having names like this, this actually means your database structure is wrong. Read some about `nf3 database`. http://phlonx.com/resources/nf3/

Comment: What new `join` for? Any changes in `where` ?

Comment: This is very old structure.. changing that means.. lots of changes.. i will work on that later.. uptill now that isn't slowing down the results..

Comment: use `desc` index for `desc` sorting.

Comment: How can i use EXPLAIN in PHP? i am kind of lost :(

Comment: Please note that the result is now in cache.. so it is taking 2 seconds.. but if i run fresh query.. it takes more than 12 seconds :(

Answer (score 0):

change this new line to

```
    LEFT JOIN ".TBL_USER_ONLINE." o  on ON a.user_id=o.user_id
```

EDIT :
then your problem is with the ORDER BY.
your query takes longs time to ORDER BY two `user_id` of two tables, try use just one `user_id`
from one table

EDIT2 :

add this `o.user_id` also to the `SELECT` part
like that

```
 SELECT
a.i_am,a.seeking_a,
a.zodiac,
a.my_marital_status,
a.city,a.country,
a.my_age,
a.intrested_in1,
a.intrested_in2,
a.intrested_in3,
a.intrested_in4,
a.intrested_in5,
a.intrested_in6,
a.user_id,
a.picture_type,
a.photo,
a.block_photo,
r.username,
u.title,
u.about_myself
o.user_id                 <-- New Line
```

Comment: i did as you said.. but not much improvement.. please see my two EXPLAINED query.. and see if you can shed some light

Comment: I already did that in both EXPLAIN queries above.. if you see carefully **o.user_id as online_user_id**  :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely in the sorting.  Whereas in the first query MySQL could sort using the `a.user_id` index, in the second query it must perform a `filesort` of a million records in order to sort over the columns of two tables (and then seek to some point in the resultset to effect the `LIMIT` clause).

Sorting by `o.user_id` should be sufficient, since it is either `NULL` or equal to `a.user_id`.

Also, if you were instead able to restrict the query with an inequality on `o.user_id` in a `WHERE` clause, you would at least not need to seek as far.

Comment: i did that... but no use.. please see my explained query in in edited question now

Answer (score 0):

why you use order by on two columns

```
ORDER BY o.user_id DESC, a.user_id DESC
```

I think o.user_id and a.user_id will be same values for a single user so you can just use one.

o.user_id if you want to include null from tables TBL_USER_ONLINE in order 
a.user_id if you want to order only on user ids.

Also use EXPLAIN and create any necessary indexes for joins, where conditions and order by columns

Comment: How to use EXPLAIN in PHP.. can you please tell me?

Comment: print query and run that on mysql client with EXPLAIN e.g. (explain select * from table1 where abc=111;)  it will show various information about query execution. most important column is "key" if its empty then no index is used for the table. you need to create indexes for table and concerned columns.

Comment: by seeing explain output and query. row scan for mysite_about_myself_new is large (30011). can you put more filters and try order on a.user_id instead of o.user_id. as user_id index is not in use for mysite_about_myself_new which will be helpfull to scan row.

Comment: did as you said.. please see my edited answer now.. thank you so much for taking interest

Comment: you can see scan rows comes down to 38 from 30011. check for the actual resultset of the query if you are satisfied with the resultset use the query

Comment: But then how will I put Online users on top if it is not orders by o.user_index ? can you suggest me some alternative? What is going wrong here?

Comment: try removing index i_am from table mysite_about_myself_new and user o.user_index in order by

Comment: how much data you expect without limit. if it is comparable to rowscan (30011) then not much can be done at sql level but caching. if actual result set is small you can try to create combine index on a.approved, a.i_am, a.seeking_a